# How to get max record value from every record that has same ID using join table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, reference, max

i dont have any idea to get max record value from many records that have same id and joined with another table. i hope someone could help me here.
this the table:
order_id     name     result1     result2       result3              max_date                admin                 seq2              extern

---

517             A                   97                  65                  77                      23-DEC-14               Rey                         2                       null
617             B                   null                null          null                 null                                                    5                    6
517             A               null                null               null             18-DEC-14              Roo                       1                      2
617                     B                   44                  78                  80                 22-DEC-14               Tow                             6                     5

result that i want is like this:
order_id        name            result1         result2             result3                 max_date                admin              seq2         extern

---

517                     A                        97                         65                           77                             23-DEC-14              Rey                        2                   2 
617                  B                       44                         78                          80                            22-DEC-14              Tow                       6                   6

i try this query, but it just gave one result:

```
WITH t AS   
(SELECT x.order_id,x.name,x.extern_order_status as extern,y.result1, y.result2, y.result3, 
t_logging_max.xd1 as max_date,
p_agent_admin.username as admin,
MAX(y.seq) AS seq2  
FROM   t_order_demand x      
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
      SELECT id,xn1, MAX(xd1) AS xd1
      FROM t_logging
      GROUP BY id,xn1
  ) t_logging_max ON x.order_id = t_logging_max.id
LEFT JOIN
  (
      SELECT agent_id,username
      FROM p_agent
      GROUP BY agent_id,username
  ) p_agent_admin ON t_logging_max.xn1 = p_agent_admin.agent_id       
JOIN   t_order_log y      
ON     x.order_id = y.order_id    
and    y.order_id LIKE '%10%'         
GROUP  BY x.order_id,x.name,x.extern_order_status,y.result1, y.result2,y.result3,t_logging_max.xd1,p_agent_admin.username) 
SELECT * FROM   t WHERE (t.seq2) IN (SELECT MAX(tt.seq2) FROM t tt);
```

actually there must be more than 2 records that id has **%10%** 
hope u could help me. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Group by` with `Max Aggregate` should work. Except the `Admin` Column which is holding a `varchar` value.

```
SELECT order_id,
       NAME,
       Max(result1) result1,
       Max(result2) result2,
       Max(result3) result3,
       Max(max_date) max_date,
       Max(admin) admin,
       Max(seq2) seq2,
       Max(extern) extern
FROM   tablename
GROUP  BY order_id,
          NAME
```